# How to add associative array Elements together grouped by their index

Tags: php, mysql

My boss wants to show the most popular states that people request franchising data from.  I'm working with zipcodes that users put in.   I run it through a function to find the state, but the problem is I have a count for each zip code not a total for the state itself.  I need to combine the totals for each zip code(into one total for the state).

I'm able to add all these up by putting a counter in the loop but it does not break for each state.  So I guess the solution would be a way break the loop when the state changes? so currently the output is as such:

New York - 8
New York - 11
New York -236
New York - 7
California - 2
Alabama - 7

I need to add all of new york into one category.

```
<?php
include("databaseClass.php");
$databaseClass = new databaseClass();
$conn = $databaseClass->connect();
$countFranArr = array();
$running = 0;


$sqlFranCount = "select client_zip, count(*) as total from request_form_commits inner join franchise on franchise.franchise_id = request_form_commits.franchise_id 
                where time_of_request >= '2011-03-20 18:01:04' and time_of_request <= '2033-03-20 21:03:22' group by client_zip";
                   $resultFranCount = $conn->query($sqlFranCount);
                   if($resultFranCount->num_rows > 0)
                   {
                     while($rowFranCount = $resultFranCount->fetch_assoc())
                     {
                       //array_push_assoc($countCatArr, $rowCatCount['fdd_category'], $rowCatCount['total']);
                       //echo $rowCatCount['total']."<br>";
                       $countFranArr[$rowFranCount['client_zip']] = $rowFranCount['total'];
                     }
                   }


                //arsort($countFranArr);

                foreach($countFranArr as $zip=>$total)
                { 
                    //echo $databaseClass->getState($zip)." - ".$total."<br>";
                    $state = $databaseClass->getState($zip);
                    if($state == "")
                    {
                        echo "";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo $state." - ".$total."<br>";
                        $running = $running + $total;
                    }

                }
echo $running;


?>
```

Expected results will be

New York 267
California - 3
etc...

One total count for each state so I can order them by most popular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do it in your first loop, here's one:

```
while($rowFranCount = $resultFranCount->fetch_assoc()) {
    $state = $databaseClass->getState($rowFranCount['client_zip']);

    if(!isset($result[$state])) {
        $result[$state] = 0;
    }
    $result[$state] += $rowFranCount['total'];
}
```

Then loop the result to display:

```
foreach($result as $state => $total) {
    echo "$state - $total<br>";
}
```

Comment: You're the man! Or the woman if you're a lady.  Did exactly what I need.